# Returning unsigned long long from an extension function in PHP

Tags: php, php-extension

If i need to return a long i simply use the RETURN_LONG macro. But what do i do if i need to return an unsigned long long. If i use this macro the data gets corrupted...

Answer (score 3):

Return it as a string like [bcmath](http://php.net/ref.bc) does.